# Retrieving HTML Info with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am very new to using Beautiful Soup and struggling to grasp how to retrieve my intended data. I have the following source code:

```
<pre>
<div class="scorebox_meta">
<div><strong><a href="https://fbref.com/en/matches/2021-08-14">Saturday August 14, 2021</a></strong>,<span class="venuetime" data-venue-date="2021-08-14" data-venue-time="12:30" data-venue-epoch="1628940600">12:30 (venue time)</span> <span class="localtime" data-label="your time">13:30 (local time)</span>
</div><div><strong><small>Venue</small></strong>: <small>Old Trafford, Manchester</small></div>
</pre>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the date (2021-08-14), time (12:30), and venue location (Old Trafford, Manchester), but the code I've written returns either "none" or all the information in the scorebox. Can anyone assist?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://fbref.com/en/matches/e62685d4/Manchester-United-Leeds-United-August-14-2021-Premier-League"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
scorebox = soup.find("div", class_="scorebox_meta")

date = scorebox.select("div", class_="data-venue-date")
time = scorebox.select("div", class_="data-venue-time")
venue = scorebox.select("div", class_="match_stadium")

print("Date:", date)
print("Time:", time)
print("Venue:", venue)
```

Comment: For all three, I get a long html string "[<div><strong><a href="/en/matches/2021-08-14">Saturday August 14, 2021</a></strong>, <span class="venuetime" data-venue-date="2021-08-14" data-venue-epoch="1628940600" data-venue-time="12:30">12:30 (venue time)</span> <span class="localtime" data-label="your time"></span></div>, <div><a href="/en/comps/9/2021-2022/2021-2022-Premier-League-Stats">Premier League</a> (Matchweek 1)</div>, <div>...". Is there a way to limit the value to just the date, time, and venue?

Comment: And you want text only?

Comment: Exactly. I tried adding ".text' but returns that it has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @Henry I guess, OP wants text rather then element. From _I'm trying to retrieve the date (2021-08-14), time (12:30), and venue location (Old Trafford, Manchester)_ And also, `<pre>` was not there in OP question.

Comment: @imxitiz sure, I just updated the formatting so we can see the HTML code instead of rendered output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get the information from that page:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://fbref.com/en/matches/e62685d4/Manchester-United-Leeds-United-August-14-2021-Premier-League"
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
for df in dfs:
    print(df.head())
print('\n')
```

Result in terminal:

```
Manchester Utd (4-2-3-1)    Manchester Utd (4-2-3-1).1
0   1   David de Gea
1   2   Victor Lindelöf
2   5   Harry Maguire
3   6   Paul Pogba
4   11  Mason Greenwood


Leeds United (4-1-4-1)  Leeds United (4-1-4-1).1
0   1   Illan Meslier
1   2   Luke Ayling
2   5   Robin Koch
3   6   Liam Cooper
4   9   Patrick Bamford


Manchester Utd  Leeds United
Possession  Possession
0   49% 51%
1   Passing Accuracy    Passing Accuracy
2   363 of 465 — 78%    77% — 372 of 482
3   Shots on Target Shots on Target
4   8 of 16 — 50%   30% — 3 of 10


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Performance Expected    SCA Passes  Carries Take-Ons
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min Gls Ast PK  PKatt   Sh  SoT CrdY    CrdR    Touches Tkl Int Blocks  xG  npxG    xAG SCA GCA Cmp Att Cmp%    PrgP    Carries PrgC    Att Succ
0   Mason Greenwood 11.0    eng ENG FW,RW   19-317  90  1   0   0   0   3   2   0   0   38  0   0   1   0.1 0.1 0.3 5   1   22  27  81.5    4   28  3   9   5
1   Paul Pogba  6.0 fr FRA  LW  28-152  74  0   4   0   0   2   1   0   0   46  1   1   1   0.3 0.3 0.7 5   4   25  33  75.8    5   29  2   2   1
2   Anthony Martial 9.0 fr FRA  FW  25-252  16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0   0   5   7   71.4    1   5   0   2   2
3   Daniel James    21.0    wls WAL RW  23-277  74  0   0   0   0   3   1   0   0   34  2   0   2   0.2 0.2 0.0 2   0   13  19  68.4    2   16  2   1   0
4   Jadon Sancho    25.0    eng ENG LW  21-142  16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   15  0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0   0   10  14  71.4    0   8   1   2   1


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Total   Short   Medium  Long    Unnamed: 20_level_0 Unnamed: 21_level_0 Unnamed: 22_level_0 Unnamed: 23_level_0 Unnamed: 24_level_0 Unnamed: 25_level_0 Unnamed: 26_level_0 Unnamed: 27_level_0
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min Cmp Att Cmp%    TotDist PrgDist Cmp Att Cmp%    Cmp Att Cmp%    Cmp Att Cmp%    Ast xAG xA  KP  1/3 PPA CrsPA   PrgP
0   Mason Greenwood 11.0    eng ENG FW,RW   19-317  90  22  27  81.5    319 102 13  14  92.9    8   8   100.0   1   4   25.0    0   0.3 0.1 1   3   2   0   4
1   Paul Pogba  6.0 fr FRA  LW  28-152  74  25  33  75.8    523 212 10  15  66.7    6   7   85.7    7   8   87.5    4   0.7 0.5 5   3   2   0   5
2   Anthony Martial 9.0 fr FRA  FW  25-252  16  5   7   71.4    79  14  2   2   100.0   3   4   75.0    0   0   NaN 0   0.0 0.0 0   1   0   0   1
3   Daniel James    21.0    wls WAL RW  23-277  74  13  19  68.4    114 33  11  12  91.7    1   2   50.0    0   1   0.0 0   0.0 0.0 1   1   0   0   2
4   Jadon Sancho    25.0    eng ENG LW  21-142  16  10  14  71.4    113 3   6   8   75.0    3   5   60.0    0   0   NaN 0   0.0 0.0 0   0   0   0   0


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Unnamed: 6_level_0  Pass Types  Corner Kicks    Outcomes
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min Att Live    Dead    FK  TB  Sw  Crs TI  CK  In  Out Str Cmp Off Blocks
0   Mason Greenwood 11.0    eng ENG FW,RW   19-317  90  27  25  2   0   3   0   2   0   2   2   0   0   22  0   0
1   Paul Pogba  6.0 fr FRA  LW  28-152  74  33  32  1   1   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   25  0   1
2   Anthony Martial 9.0 fr FRA  FW  25-252  16  7   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   1
3   Daniel James    21.0    wls WAL RW  23-277  74  19  19  0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   13  0   1
4   Jadon Sancho    25.0    eng ENG LW  21-142  16  14  13  1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   10  0   0


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Tackles Challenges  Blocks  Unnamed: 18_level_0 Unnamed: 19_level_0 Unnamed: 20_level_0 Unnamed: 21_level_0
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min Tkl TklW    Def 3rd Mid 3rd Att 3rd Tkl Att Tkl%    Lost    Blocks  Sh  Pass    Int Tkl+Int Clr Err
0   Mason Greenwood 11.0    eng ENG FW,RW   19-317  90  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NaN 0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
1   Paul Pogba  6.0 fr FRA  LW  28-152  74  1   1   0   1   0   1   3   33.3    2   1   0   1   1   2   0   0
2   Anthony Martial 9.0 fr FRA  FW  25-252  16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   Daniel James    21.0    wls WAL RW  23-277  74  2   1   0   2   0   0   0   NaN 0   2   0   2   0   2   1   0
4   Jadon Sancho    25.0    eng ENG LW  21-142  16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Touches Take-Ons    Carries Receiving
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min Touches Def Pen Def 3rd Mid 3rd Att 3rd Att Pen Live    Att Succ    Succ%   Tkld    Tkld%   Carries TotDist PrgDist PrgC    1/3 CPA Mis Dis Rec PrgR
0   Mason Greenwood 11.0    eng ENG FW,RW   19-317  90  38  0   3   16  21  2   38  9   5   55.6    4   44.4    28  180 111 3   3   2   3   2   28  6
1   Paul Pogba  6.0 fr FRA  LW  28-152  74  46  1   3   23  20  3   46  2   1   50.0    1   50.0    29  125 73  2   3   1   6   3   35  6
2   Anthony Martial 9.0 fr FRA  FW  25-252  16  7   0   1   6   1   0   7   2   2   100.0   0   0.0 5   57  25  0   0   0   0   0   6   1
3   Daniel James    21.0    wls WAL RW  23-277  74  34  1   2   13  19  5   34  1   0   0.0 1   100.0   16  132 48  2   1   1   3   1   21  10
4   Jadon Sancho    25.0    eng ENG LW  21-142  16  15  0   1   8   6   0   15  2   1   50.0    1   50.0    8   44  24  1   1   0   0   0   13  0


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Performance Aerial Duels
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min CrdY    CrdR    2CrdY   Fls Fld Off Crs Int TklW    PKwon   PKcon   OG  Recov   Won Lost    Won%
0   Mason Greenwood 11.0    eng ENG FW,RW   19-317  90  0   0   0   2   1   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   2   0.0
1   Paul Pogba  6.0 fr FRA  LW  28-152  74  0   0   0   2   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   5   1   1   50.0
2   Anthony Martial 9.0 fr FRA  FW  25-252  16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   NaN
3   Daniel James    21.0    wls WAL RW  23-277  74  0   0   0   0   0   2   2   0   1   0   0   0   3   1   1   50.0
4   Jadon Sancho    25.0    eng ENG LW  21-142  16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NaN


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Shot Stopping   Launched    Passes  Goal Kicks  Crosses Sweeper
Player  Nation  Age Min SoTA    GA  Saves   Save%   PSxG    Cmp Att Cmp%    Att Thr Launch% AvgLen  Att Launch% AvgLen  Opp Stp Stp%    #OPA    AvgDist
0   David de Gea    es ESP  30-280  90  3   1   2   66.7    1.0 7   11  63.6    24  3   8.3 20.8    12  75.0    42.5    12  0   0.0 0   12.0


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Performance Expected    SCA Passes  Carries Take-Ons
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min Gls Ast PK  PKatt   Sh  SoT CrdY    CrdR    Touches Tkl Int Blocks  xG  npxG    xAG SCA GCA Cmp Att Cmp%    PrgP    Carries PrgC    Att Succ
0   Patrick Bamford 9.0 eng ENG FW  27-343  76  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   25  0   1   1   0.1 0.1 0.1 1   0   12  14  85.7    2   12  0   0   0
1   Tyler Roberts   11.0    wls WAL FW  22-214  14  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   6   1   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.2 1   0   3   3   100.0   1   3   0   0   0
2   Jack Harrison   22.0    eng ENG LM  24-267  68  0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   31  1   1   1   0.0 0.0 0.1 3   0   14  21  66.7    3   24  0   1   1
3   Hélder Costa    17.0    ao ANG  LM  27-214  22  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   9   0   0   1   0.0 0.0 0.0 1   0   5   5   100.0   0   6   0   0   0
4   Mateusz Klich   43.0    pl POL  FW,CM   31-062  90  0   0   0   0   2   1   0   0   49  2   0   0   0.1 0.1 0.0 2   0   34  46  73.9    3   31  2   1   1


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Total   Short   Medium  Long    Unnamed: 20_level_0 Unnamed: 21_level_0 Unnamed: 22_level_0 Unnamed: 23_level_0 Unnamed: 24_level_0 Unnamed: 25_level_0 Unnamed: 26_level_0 Unnamed: 27_level_0
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min Cmp Att Cmp%    TotDist PrgDist Cmp Att Cmp%    Cmp Att Cmp%    Cmp Att Cmp%    Ast xAG xA  KP  1/3 PPA CrsPA   PrgP
0   Patrick Bamford 9.0 eng ENG FW  27-343  76  12  14  85.7    141 25  10  12  83.3    0   0   NaN 1   1   100.0   0   0.1 0.0 1   0   1   0   2
1   Tyler Roberts   11.0    wls WAL FW  22-214  14  3   3   100.0   70  22  1   1   100.0   1   1   100.0   1   1   100.0   0   0.2 0.0 1   0   2   1   1
2   Jack Harrison   22.0    eng ENG LM  24-267  68  14  21  66.7    215 94  7   10  70.0    5   6   83.3    1   3   33.3    0   0.1 0.0 2   3   0   0   3
3   Hélder Costa    17.0    ao ANG  LM  27-214  22  5   5   100.0   79  0   2   2   100.0   3   3   100.0   0   0   NaN 0   0.0 0.0 0   0   0   0   0
4   Mateusz Klich   43.0    pl POL  FW,CM   31-062  90  34  46  73.9    518 80  19  21  90.5    12  16  75.0    2   5   40.0    0   0.0 0.0 0   3   0   0   3


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Unnamed: 6_level_0  Pass Types  Corner Kicks    Outcomes
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min Att Live    Dead    FK  TB  Sw  Crs TI  CK  In  Out Str Cmp Off Blocks
0   Patrick Bamford 9.0 eng ENG FW  27-343  76  14  8   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   12  0   0
1   Tyler Roberts   11.0    wls WAL FW  22-214  14  3   3   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0
2   Jack Harrison   22.0    eng ENG LM  24-267  68  21  21  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   14  0   1
3   Hélder Costa    17.0    ao ANG  LM  27-214  22  5   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   0
4   Mateusz Klich   43.0    pl POL  FW,CM   31-062  90  46  44  1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   34  1   1


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Tackles Challenges  Blocks  Unnamed: 18_level_0 Unnamed: 19_level_0 Unnamed: 20_level_0 Unnamed: 21_level_0
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min Tkl TklW    Def 3rd Mid 3rd Att 3rd Tkl Att Tkl%    Lost    Blocks  Sh  Pass    Int Tkl+Int Clr Err
0   Patrick Bamford 9.0 eng ENG FW  27-343  76  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0.0 1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
1   Tyler Roberts   11.0    wls WAL FW  22-214  14  1   0   0   1   0   0   0   NaN 0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
2   Jack Harrison   22.0    eng ENG LM  24-267  68  1   0   0   1   0   1   2   50.0    1   1   0   1   1   2   0   0
3   Hélder Costa    17.0    ao ANG  LM  27-214  22  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NaN 0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
4   Mateusz Klich   43.0    pl POL  FW,CM   31-062  90  2   1   0   1   1   2   2   100.0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Touches Take-Ons    Carries Receiving
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min Touches Def Pen Def 3rd Mid 3rd Att 3rd Att Pen Live    Att Succ    Succ%   Tkld    Tkld%   Carries TotDist PrgDist PrgC    1/3 CPA Mis Dis Rec PrgR
0   Patrick Bamford 9.0 eng ENG FW  27-343  76  25  0   0   17  8   3   25  0   0   NaN 0   NaN 12  19  3   0   0   0   5   1   16  2
1   Tyler Roberts   11.0    wls WAL FW  22-214  14  6   0   0   2   4   1   6   0   0   NaN 0   NaN 3   9   4   0   0   0   1   0   4   2
2   Jack Harrison   22.0    eng ENG LM  24-267  68  31  0   5   19  7   0   31  1   1   100.0   0   0.0 24  78  25  0   0   0   4   0   22  6
3   Hélder Costa    17.0    ao ANG  LM  27-214  22  9   0   2   4   3   0   9   0   0   NaN 0   NaN 6   18  1   0   0   0   1   0   6   2
4   Mateusz Klich   43.0    pl POL  FW,CM   31-062  90  49  0   6   28  16  1   49  1   1   100.0   0   0.0 31  180 72  2   1   0   1   1   39  9


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Performance Aerial Duels
Player  #   Nation  Pos Age Min CrdY    CrdR    2CrdY   Fls Fld Off Crs Int TklW    PKwon   PKcon   OG  Recov   Won Lost    Won%
0   Patrick Bamford 9.0 eng ENG FW  27-343  76  0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   2   0.0
1   Tyler Roberts   11.0    wls WAL FW  22-214  14  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0.0
2   Jack Harrison   22.0    eng ENG LM  24-267  68  0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   3   0   1   0.0
3   Hélder Costa    17.0    ao ANG  LM  27-214  22  0   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0.0
4   Mateusz Klich   43.0    pl POL  FW,CM   31-062  90  0   0   0   2   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   6   0   0   NaN


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Shot Stopping   Launched    Passes  Goal Kicks  Crosses Sweeper
Player  Nation  Age Min SoTA    GA  Saves   Save%   PSxG    Cmp Att Cmp%    Att Thr Launch% AvgLen  Att Launch% AvgLen  Opp Stp Stp%    #OPA    AvgDist
0   Illan Meslier   fr FRA  21-165  90  8   5   3   37.5    1.6 5   20  25.0    37  10  37.8    30.2    10  60.0    44.5    10  1   10.0    2   13.3


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Unnamed: 6_level_0  Unnamed: 7_level_0  Unnamed: 8_level_0  SCA 1   SCA 2
Minute  Player  Squad   xG  PSxG    Outcome Distance    Body Part   Notes   Player  Event   Player  Event
0   2.0 Scott McTominay Manchester Utd  0.03    NaN Blocked 15.0    Right Foot  NaN Bruno Fernandes Pass (Live) Daniel James    Pass (Live)
1   6.0 Mason Greenwood Manchester Utd  0.02    0.13    Saved   28.0    Left Foot   NaN Scott McTominay Pass (Live) Bruno Fernandes Pass (Live)
2   9.0 Mateusz Klich   Leeds United    0.02    NaN Off Target  22.0    Right Foot  NaN Jack Harrison   Pass (Live) Raphinha    Pass (Dead)
3   11.0    Harry Maguire   Manchester Utd  0.01    NaN Off Target  14.0    Head    NaN Luke Shaw   Pass (Dead) NaN NaN
4   12.0    Paul Pogba  Manchester Utd  0.25    NaN Off Target  16.0    Left Foot   NaN Mason Greenwood Pass (Live) Mason Greenwood Take-On


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Unnamed: 6_level_0  Unnamed: 7_level_0  Unnamed: 8_level_0  SCA 1   SCA 2
Minute  Player  Squad   xG  PSxG    Outcome Distance    Body Part   Notes   Player  Event   Player  Event
0   2.0 Scott McTominay Manchester Utd  0.03    NaN Blocked 15.0    Right Foot  NaN Bruno Fernandes Pass (Live) Daniel James    Pass (Live)
1   6.0 Mason Greenwood Manchester Utd  0.02    0.13    Saved   28.0    Left Foot   NaN Scott McTominay Pass (Live) Bruno Fernandes Pass (Live)
2   11.0    Harry Maguire   Manchester Utd  0.01    NaN Off Target  14.0    Head    NaN Luke Shaw   Pass (Dead) NaN NaN
3   12.0    Paul Pogba  Manchester Utd  0.25    NaN Off Target  16.0    Left Foot   NaN Mason Greenwood Pass (Live) Mason Greenwood Take-On
4   15.0    Daniel James    Manchester Utd  0.03    NaN Blocked 17.0    Left Foot   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN


Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0  Unnamed: 3_level_0  Unnamed: 4_level_0  Unnamed: 5_level_0  Unnamed: 6_level_0  Unnamed: 7_level_0  Unnamed: 8_level_0  SCA 1   SCA 2
Minute  Player  Squad   xG  PSxG    Outcome Distance    Body Part   Notes   Player  Event   Player  Event
0   9.0 Mateusz Klich   Leeds United    0.02    NaN Off Target  22.0    Right Foot  NaN Jack Harrison   Pass (Live) Raphinha    Pass (Dead)
1   16.0    Jack Harrison   Leeds United    0.02    0.05    Saved   25.0    Left Foot   Volley  Mateusz Klich   Pass (Live) Raphinha    Pass (Dead)
2   16.0    Mateusz Klich   Leeds United    0.04    0.39    Saved   27.0    Right Foot  NaN Mateusz Klich   Take-On Jack Harrison   Pass (Live)
3   26.0    Patrick Bamford Leeds United    0.12    NaN Off Target  10.0    Head    NaN Raphinha    Pass (Dead) Jack Harrison   Fouled
4   34.0    Raphinha    Leeds United    0.05    NaN Blocked 20.0    Left Foot   NaN Patrick Bamford Pass (Live) Stuart Dallas   Pass (Live)


​
```

​
Pick the table(s) you want. Pandas documentation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html).

Edit: here is another way to get the particular info OP is after:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://fbref.com/en/matches/e62685d4/Manchester-United-Leeds-United-August-14-2021-Premier-League"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
scorebox = soup.find("div", class_="scorebox_meta")

date = scorebox.select_one('span[class="venuetime"]').get('data-venue-date')
time = scorebox.select_one('span[class="venuetime"]').get('data-venue-time')
venue = scorebox.find('small', string='Venue').find_next('small').text

print(date, time, venue)
```

Result in terminal:

```
2021-08-14 12:30 Old Trafford, Manchester
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty familiar with pandas and would have preferred to use it. Unfortunately, the specific data I'm looking for doesn't exist in a table so pd.read_html doesn't work for this.

Comment: I understand @ewolf. I edited my answer and included a way to get those bits you're after.

Comment: thank you! Adding the 'span' portion and the select_one was exactly the thing I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

In `scorebox.select("div", class_="data-venue-date")` it's not selecting specific class with "data-venue-date", but it's just selecting all div in 'scorebox'.

**PLUS:** "data-venue-date" is not a class but it is attribute, also it's not the attribute of "div" but attribute of "span" element.

To do as you wanted:

```
print(scorebox.find("span", {"data-venue-date" : re.compile(r".*")}))
# <span class="venuetime" data-venue-date="2021-08-14" data-venue-epoch="1628940600" data-venue-time="12:30">12:30 (venue time)</span>
```

But we don't need to do this, we can do:

```
print(scorebox.find("div").text)
print(scorebox.find_all("div")[-2].text)
```

1. Selecting first "div" inside `scorebox`
2. Selecting second last "div" of `scorebox`

Output:

```
Saturday August 14, 2021, 12:30 (venue time) 
Venue: Old Trafford, Manchester
```

Comment: Checked for some other matches also, and it's working perfectly fine. :)